# How to implement a tool to validate content and push it to the cloud

Tags: database, git, architecture, cloud

I am currently committing text files and images to a GitHub repository that need to have a certain format and content style, with validation done via pre-commit hooks, so all files committed to the repository are valid. I also need git to keep track of when files are updated and the versions that existed previously.

In the future I want to move to storing the files to a cloud service instead of the repository. This is the solution I though of:

1. Have a script that needs the directory you are trying to upload, name would need to be a certain format, ex. `<City><Street>`.
2. If it exists, the script compares the folder contents to the one in the cloud, if not all the folder gets uploaded.
3. Before upload we run content format validation, if it doesn't pass then we throw errors to the user.
4. If there were previous file versions, we store them in a different folder, appending the date/time to the filename.
5. Cloud now has the latest version.

I would lose a lot of the advantages that I had with version control and the pre-commit hooks before. I would gain the ability to just pull a specific folder, something that GitHub doesn't allow me to do. What would be a better way to implement this? Is there a tool that would be good for this?

Comment: S3 + Lambda can do the job on AWS

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I am also looking into what I can do with Google Cloud.